# What is causing this php syntax error?

Tags: php

I'm usually pretty good about tracking down syntax errors but I cannot, for the life of me, find and correct this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting T_FUNCTION in /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/trackstar/protected/controllers/IssueControll er.php on line 207
```

Line 207 is the last line with the closing delimiter: ?>

```
<?php

class IssueController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
     * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
     */
    public $layout='//layouts/column2';
    private $_project = null;

    /**
     * @return array action filters
     */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'projectContext + create', //check to ensure valid project context
        );
    }

    /**
     * Specifies the access control rules.
     * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
     * @return array access control rules
     */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a particular model.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Issue;
            $model->project_id = $this->_project->id;
        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Issue']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Issue'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Updates a particular model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Issue']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Issue'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a particular model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
        {
            // we only allow deletion via POST request
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }
        else
            throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }

    /**
     * Lists all models.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Issue');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Manages all models.
     */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Issue('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Issue']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Issue'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
     * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
     * @param integer the ID of the model to be loaded
     */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Issue::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
     * Performs the AJAX validation.
     * @param CModel the model to be validated
     */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='issue-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }

    protected function loadProject($project_id) 
    {
        if($this->_project===null)
        {
            $this->_project=Project::model()->findbyPk($project_id);
            if($this->_project===null)
            {
                throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested project does not
                exist.');
            }
        }
            return $this->_project;     

    }

    public function filterProjectContext($filterChain)
    {
        $projectId = null;
        if(isset($_GET['pid'])){
            $projectId = $_GET['pid'];
        } else {
            if(isset($_POST['pid'])){
                $projectId = $_POST['pid'];
            }
            $this->loadProject($projectId);
        }
        $filterChain->run();
    }
?>
```

Does anybody have any idea where this error is at?

Comment: Having an editor which highlights brackets who don't have a corresponding closing bracket would have been helpful in this instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to close your class with a `}`.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't close your class declaration.

Answer (score 4):

you need to add another closing "}" for the class.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the class closing bracket `}`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you haven't closed your class.

You need to add a `}` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You have not closed your class declaration.

You should have a final closing brace

```
}

?>
```